# why dont bundle css files mvc core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm use mvc core 2 I  want bundle  css and js file 
I'm add css file in wwwroot.when bundle css don't  load css for webpage
plasee see  this pic path wwwroot [![path css ][]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DogRp.png)
Layout file  is in Areas name identity
I'm try this code
  **Configure inn startup.cs**

```
  app.UseFileServer();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\css\Css-admin")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/Css-admin")

            });

            app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\css\Css-admin")),
                RequestPath = "/Css-admin"
            });
            app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                   Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\css\Css-admin\colors")),
                RequestPath = "/Css-admin"
            });

bundelconfig.json
     {
        "outputFileName":"wwwroot/css/admin.min.css",
        "inputFiles": [
          "wwwroot/css/Css-admin/bootstrap.min.css",
          "wwwroot/css/Css-admin/custom-bootstrap-rtl.css",
          "wwwroot/css/Css-admin/chartist.min.css",
          "wwwroot/css/Css-admin/chartist-init.css",
          "wwwroot/css/Css-admin/css-chart.css",
          "wwwroot/css/Css-admin/style.css",
          "wwwroot/css/Css-admin/colors/green.css",
          "wwwroot/css/Css-admin/multi-select.css",
          "wwwroot/css/Css-admin/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css",
          "wwwroot/css/Css-admin/select2.min.css",
          "wwwroot/css/Css-admin/bootstrap-select.min.css",
          "wwwroot/css/Css-admin/bootstrap-tagsinput.css",
          "wwwroot/css/Css-admin/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.css"
        ],
        "minify": {
          "enabled": true,
          "renameLocals": false,
          "adjustRelativePaths": false,
          "commentMode": "all"
        },
        "sourceMap": false
      },
```

**add css link to layout**  asmin.min.css when bundle is empty

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/admin.min.css" asp-file-version="true" />
```

Comment: Have you enabled bundle on build or only on publish?

Comment: how enable bundle on build or publish

Comment: See [Ad hoc execution of bundling and minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x#ad-hoc-execution-of-bundling-and-minification)